# Add more than one user to an image with Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I can add a user to an docker image using Dockerfile with following command:

```
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash [username]
USER [username]
WORKDIR /home/[username]
```

However, If I want to add more than one user to an image with following command, I encounter with an error for second user:

```
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash [username1]
USER [username1]
WORKDIR /home/[username1]

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash [username2]
USER [username2]
WORKDIR /home/[username2]
```

Error message is:

useradd: Permission denied.

useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.

Answer (score 5):

This is because second `useradd` command is running as username1 which does not have sufficient privileges to add user

Moving the second useradd before `USER [username1]` would make it work for you

```
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash username1
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash username2
USER username1
WORKDIR /home/username1

USER username2
WORKDIR /home/username2
```